# Saving an audio file in documents directory

Tags: iphone, mpmediapickercontroller

**I am selecting an audio file using MPMediaPickerController, once I select, I want it to store into my application sandbox (some where in documents directory). Is there any way to do so?**

```
//I am implementing MPMediaPickerController delegates

- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
    //Here I can store selected audio into my application sandbox, but don't know how?

    NSLog(@"%@",[mediaItemCollection description]);
}
```

Comment: try this tutorial:-http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/07/19/from-iphone-media-library-to-pcm-samples-in-dozens-of-confounding-potentially-lossy-steps/